# corresponding system of equation of the given solution space

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, analysis

The following question seems to me interesting. it gives solution space and required the corresponding system of equation. The question is the following:

Consider the vectors in $R^4$ defined by

$a_1=(-1,0,1,2)$, $a_2=(3,4,-2,5)$, $a_3=(1,4,0,9)$.

Find a system of homogeneous linear equations for which the space of solutions is exactly subspace of $R^4$ spanned by the three given vectors.

First i check the linear independence of the given vectors to see form of the generated space. But after determining i only obtained the result that the rank of the coefficient matrix of the  corresponding homogeneous system of equations is $2$. i obtained this result by rank-nullity theorem. But i can't go further. Please help.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

@Rory Daulton has given a solution in terms of a determinant. i will propose another solution that avoids determinant.

use your vectors $a_1^T, a_2^T, a_3^T$ as rows and make up a matrix $ B = \pmatrix{-1 & 0 & 1 & 2\\3 & 4 & -2 & 5\\1 & 4 & 0 & 9}.$ the null space of $B$ will be the coefficient matrix we are looking for. solving $B \pmatrix{x \\y\\z\\w} = \pmatrix{0 \\ 0 \\ 0}$ you will find $A = \pmatrix{4 & -1 & 4 & 0\\8 & -11 & 0 & 4}$
so that $BA^T = \pmatrix{0 & 0\\0 & 0\\0& 0}$ which is the same as $AB^T$ is the zero matrix.

so your homogeneous system of equations are $A \pmatrix{x\\y\\z\\w} = \pmatrix{0\\0}.$

Comment: I see that my answer is wrong. I have deleted it, and note that @abel has apparently given the only correct answer here.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the normal vector, i.e. $x$ such that $a_i\cdot x = 0$ for all $i  =1,2,3$.
2. Your equation is $a\cdot x = 0$.